# Convert index in column header in python dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to convert python dataframe into column headers. I am using transpose function but results are not as expected. Which function can be used to accomplish the results as given below?

data is:

```
Year    2020
Month   SEPTEMBER
Filed Date  29-11-2020
Year    2022
Month   JULY
Filed Date  20-08-2022
Year    2022
Month   APRIL
Filed Date  20-05-2022
Year    2017
Month   AUGUST
Filed Date  21-09-2017
Year    2018
Month   JULY
Filed Date  03-02-2019
Year    2021
Month   MAY
Filed Date  22-06-2021
Year    2017
Month   DECEMBER
Filed Date  19-01-2018
Year    2018
Month   MAY
Filed Date  03-02-2019
Year    2019
Month   MARCH
Filed Date  28-09-2019
```

and convert it into:

```
Year     Month     Filed Date
2020     September 29-11-2020
2022     July      20-08-2022
```

Comment: Is the "Year Month Filled Date Year Month Filled Date..." in the first df a column?

Comment: We can use "Year month Filed date" in column or as an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [df1.iloc[i:i+3][1].tolist() for i in range(0, len(df1), 3)],
    columns=df1.iloc[0:3][0].tolist(),
)
```

print(df):

```
   Year      Month             Filed
0  2020  SEPTEMBER  Date  29-11-2020
1  2022       JULY  Date  20-08-2022
2  2022      APRIL  Date  20-05-2022
3  2017     AUGUST  Date  21-09-2017
4  2018       JULY  Date  03-02-2019
5  2021        MAY  Date  22-06-2021
6  2017   DECEMBER  Date  19-01-2018
7  2018        MAY  Date  03-02-2019
8  2019      MARCH  Date  28-09-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Here df1 is:

```
Year    2020
Month   SEPTEMBER
Filed Date  29-11-2020
Year    2022
Month   JULY
Filed Date  20-08-2022
Year    2022
Month   APRIL
Filed Date  20-05-2022
Year    2017
Month   AUGUST
Filed Date  21-09-2017
Year    2018
Month   JULY
Filed Date  03-02-2019
Year    2021
Month   MAY
Filed Date  22-06-2021
Year    2017
Month   DECEMBER
Filed Date  19-01-2018
Year    2018
Month   MAY
Filed Date  03-02-2019
Year    2019
Month   MARCH
Filed Date  28-09-2019
```

I used pivot function and approached the problem like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(df1),3):
    df= df.append(df1.pivot(columns='A', values='B', index=None).bfill(axis = 0).iloc[i])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

result:

```
A   Filed Date  Month   Year
0   29-11-2020  SEPTEMBER   2020
1   20-08-2022  JULY    2022
2   20-05-2022  APRIL   2022
3   21-09-2017  AUGUST  2017
4   03-02-2019  JULY    2018
```